# How can i make a fixed box inside a div with scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How I can make a box to be fixed within a div with scroll?

I'm trying like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #a3265e;
    font-family: 'GillSans-SemiBold';
}
.main {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 380px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 946px;*/
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.container2 {
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  background: black;
}
```

But the box is going along with the page, not only within the div.

What am i doing wrong here??? Can someone show me the way?

Thank you guys.

---

EDIT

Example -> https://jsfiddle.net/kzhuh7sv/embedded/result/

Comment: please make a jsfiddle

Comment: Of course! https://jsfiddle.net/kzhuh7sv/embedded/result/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly. Did you want the box to stay in the exact same spot when scrolling, or even when you scroll it stays there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution https://jsfiddle.net/yyt8eope/2/
I added a `div` that wraps both the container `div` and the `class='test'` `div` at the same level so the test div can be absolute inside the wrapper and be always at a fixed position

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="scroll-container">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="container2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="test">Fixed inside scroll container</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: #a3265e;
font-family: 'GillSans-SemiBold';
}
.main {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 380px;
}
.scroll-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 946px;*/
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.container2 {
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This works, one minor nitpick: `test` is rendered before `container` so any content will appear _over_ the fixed div. If you move the `test` div after the container (or give it a z-index) it will properly flow over.

Comment: thanks a lot Halcyon you were right, the text was overlapping, I added the changes you suggested to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of '`position: fixed;`' and add this '`overflow: scroll;`'.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq1m49wf/1/).

**EDIT**

Changed the JSFiddle, has been updated.

Comment: Can you explain how this is a solution? The element is not fixed.

Comment: Sorry, @Halcyon. Just re-read the question. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zq1m49wf/1/) better?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `position: fixed` since it always ties to the viewport. You want it fixed within it's context.

http://jsfiddle.net/zq1m49wf/2/

The black box stays in place as `container3` scrolls

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="container3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="test"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.container2 {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.container3 {
    height: 1500px;
}
.test {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
}
```